# Vue.js + Axios (serverless) как избежать CORS error при обращении к YooKassa?

Tags: vue.js, firebase, heroku, axios

Разрабатываю одностраничный сайт на Vue.js + Strapi.
Frontend базируется на Firebase, Strapi установлен на HerokuApp.
Все данные из админки получаю и передаю (как с localhost:8080, так и с боевого домена, делегированного на Firebase) без проблем через асинхронные методы вида:

```
await axios.get( 'https://desolate-mesa-XXXXX.herokuapp.com/infoblock' )
.then( response => ( this.infoblock= response.data )
)
```

Но возникла проблема, когда потребовалось подключить YooKassa (она же ЮКасса, она же Яндекс.Касса). По попытке создать платеж возникает сообщение:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments' from origin 'https://domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Это проблема решается, и платеж успешно оформляется, если использовать devServer proxy на Vue.js, но это работает только на машине разработчика, разумеется.

Подскажите, как лучше поступить?
Есть вариант обойтись без установки Express или подобных backend-фреймворков?
И, если нет, то как это сделать, учитывая используемые сервисы (Firebase и Heroku).

Заранее благодарствую!

P.S. Ответ ТП Яндекс.Кассы:

Насколько мы понимаем, вы пытаетесь отправить запрос на создание платежа из браузера. Так нельзя и поэтому срабатывает Access to XMLHttpRequest. Для таких запросов доступ не открывается. Для корректного взаимодействия с нашим API, вы должны выполнять запросы не из браузера, а с помощью вашего сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Firebase есть сервис Cloud Functions, я использовал его. Готовый код выглядит так:

```
  exports.yooKassa = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
    const shopId = "shopId";
    const secretKey = "secretKey";
    const t = Buffer.from(`${shopId}:${secretKey}`, "utf8").toString("base64");
    axios.post("https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments",
        {
          "amount": {
            "value": "1.00",
            "currency": "RUB",
          },
          "confirmation": {
            "type": "embedded",
          },
          "capture": true,
          "description": "description",
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Authorization": `Basic ${t}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Idempotence-Key": Date.now(),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          return res.send(response.data);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          return res.sendStatus(500);
        });
  });
});
```

Cloud Functions в этом случае работают как бэкенд.